# Parametric modules in python? Importing functions from objects

Tags: python, import

I have a module that I would like to parameterize, or rather I would like to import functions from an object.

That is I would like to be able to give it arguments that will change its behavior before I import things from it.

One way would be to make my module an object and just use those functions. Currently I do this:

```
class MyModule(object):
    def __init__(self, previous_sayings):
        self.sayings = previous_sayings
    __all__ = ['sayhi']
    def sayhi(self):
        self.sayings.append("hi!")

mod = MyModule(["oh no!"])
sayhi = mod.sayhi
sayhi()
sayhi()
print mod.sayings
```

This should print out `["oh no!", "hi!", "hi!"]`.

However, this will work less nicely the more functions you have.

I would like to be able to do something like this :

```
mod = MyModule(["oh no!"])
from mod import * 
sayhi()
sayhi()

print mod.sayings
```

Is anything like this possible? Can I inherit from a base module? How about if I add the constraint that it should look obvious to users what is going on?

Comment: It isn't clear to me why using a module would be better than using a class. Is it just that you want the ability to have the instance methods in your own namespace?

Comment: I don't care about whether the object is actually a module or class. I just want to be able to import the appropriate functions and values into the local namespace easily and have them still access the arguments I passed. does that make sense?

Comment: @JohnSalvatier: What exactly is wrong with `sayhi=mod.sayhi()`? This is a pretty common Python idiom (especially if you include equivalent code like passing `s.find` instead of `lambda x: s.find(x)` or `functools.partial(str.find, s)`), while making a module that acts like a class instance is very definitely not.

Comment: It just seems like boilerplate, but perhaps there's no good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to realize about modules:

- they are singletons, which means you will only ever have one of them, no matter how many places you import it
- you cannot pass arguments
- `from <module> import *` is dangerous, not a good habit, and should only be used with modules that have been designed that way
- all functions, classes, etc., that are defined in a module will always see that module as their global namespace.

You can get something similar to what you want:

```
8<--mod.py------------------------------------------------------
sayings = []
def sayhi():
    sayings.append("Hi!")
8<--------------------------------------------------------------

import mod
mod.sayings = ['oh no!']   # or mod.sayings.append('oh no')
from mod import sayhi
sayhi()
sayhi()
print mod.sayings
```

Comment: +1. But if (after reading all those caveats) you are going to do `from mod import *`, you really want to use `__all__` in `mod.py` to restrict what gets imported. (In this case, it would be `__all__ = ['sayhi']`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create your module then import it.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82234-importing-a-dynamically-generated-module/

Although, my suggestion would be to use a class.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is that:

```
sayhi=mod.sayhi()
saybye=mod.saybye()
# … 40 more functions
```

is more verbose than:

```
from mod import sayhi, saybye, # … 40 more functions
```

A better solution is probably just to do the importing programmatically:

```
for name in mod.__all__:
    locals[name] = getattr(mod, name)
```

Or:

```
locals.update({name: getattr(mod, name) for name in mod.__all__})
```

Comment: and then somebody will ask, "Why didn't you just do `from mod import *`?" ;)

Comment: @EthanFurman: If `mod` is a class, nobody who knows Python is going to ask that. If they do, just say, "Because `mod` isn't a module, it's an object, one of potentially many instances of the Foo class. You can't import from objects. Here's a link to the manual." (Naming the object `mod` does make it more confusing, but that's in the original post.) If `mod` really doesn't deserve to be an object and should be a module, then yes, this solution is silly. But apparently the only reason the OP didn't want an object was that "this will work less nicely the more functions you have".